# ZF2 is not letting me make anchor tag in a string

Tags: php, zend-framework2

**CODE**

```
 $responeHTml .= '<li class="col-xs-3"> <a href="'. $this->url("delete-export-rt", array("sid" => $sid, "row"=>$var->export_history[$i]["id"])).'> <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                        <div class="caption">Delete</div>
                        </a>
```

**error**

> Catchable fatal error:  Object of class Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\Url could not be converted to string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using controller helper and not view helper as you think you are.

By calling `$this->url();` in controller you get the helper instance. Then you should call `fromRoute` method to get the url.

```
$this->url()->fromRoute("delete-export-rt", array("sid" => $sid, "row"=>$var->export_history[$i]["id"]))
```

[This](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#the-url-plugin) is the plugin you're trying to use.